# Push a new view controller with navigation controller

Tags: ios

So I created a new view controller which has the Custom class named `DescriptionViewController`.
And from my current view controller inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I use this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    DescriptionViewController *descriptionViewController = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DescriptionViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:descriptionViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But nothing happens when I click on a cell. Is there anything more I need to do ?

Comment: did you set the delegate ? Is it UITableViewController or just UITableView ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath and make sure that it stops when you click on a cell. If you don't hit that breakpoint, you probably don't have a delegate set as Midhun MP suggested.

Comment: You have to set tableView.delegate = self, and add the delegates of a UITableView to the .h file.

Comment: It stops if I put a breakpoint.

Comment: NSLog self.navigationController...see if it is not nil

Comment: @Dante: yeah, it is null

Comment: Did tableView is inside a UIViewController that is part of a UINavigationController?

Comment: if it is nil.. either wrap your viewcontroller inside a navigation controller .. or use modal transition

Comment: @AndrésBrun: it is inside a view controller, but is not part of a navigation controller, but I am trying to "jump" into another view controller which has a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your viewcontroller in the storyboard and on top go to editor->embed in->navigation controller then instead of `initWithNibName` try just `init`

Comment: This gives me an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

Comment: @vBx Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboards

Comment: @vBx Then instead of initWithnibname try just init

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and it works, thanks. Maybe you should add this to your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you put in a breakpoint and it is stopping in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, my guess is that your self.navigationController is nil.

If you are using storyboards, make sure your entry point is a UINavigationController and not a UIViewController.

If you loading this view controller though a modal transition, make sure you push on a navigation controller with this view controller as the root view instead.

Comment: Yeah, I checked now, and its nil...What should I do ?