# load uiviewcontroller after click on uitableviewcell iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm little confused of how to implement simple uitableview based menu.Something like in Kayak app http://www.sendspace.com/file/igv31p
My storyboard look like this: navigation controller --->master view controller --> detail view controller. In master view controller i've got a table view. I populated it dynamically with 4 cells which are Products, Stores, Packages and Finances. All I want to do is to display child uiviewcontroller that will be a child uiviewcontroller. Something like this:
Products --> UiViewController with specific functionality
Stores --> Other UIViewControlelr with specific functionality
... and so on.

I create didselectrowatindex method
and try to do something with pushViewController like in code below method but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
StoresViewController *storeView = [[StoresViewController alloc]init];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {

            NSLog(@"Products");

            }
                break;
            case 1:{

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:storeView animated:YES];
                NSLog(@"Stores");

            }
                break;
            case 2:{
                NSLog(@"Packages");
            }
                break;
            case 3:{
                NSLog(@"Finances");

            }
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me to understand it. If this question was asked before please show me where:) Thanks in advance

Something like in Kayak app 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/igv31p

Comment: There are another post resolving that issue, take a look:

[Push a new view controller with navigation controller][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165119/push-a-new-view-controller-with-navigation-controller?noredirect=1#comment28351844_19165119

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: StoresViewController *storeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourdestinationidentifier"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this code..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                NSLog(@"Products");
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoresViewController"];

                [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
                NSLog(@"Stores");
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                NSLog(@"Packages");
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                NSLog(@"Finances");

                break;
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but errors occurred 2013-10-04 14:56:04.236 HomiesMasterDetailed[5769:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Damiano/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/C87C81DC-1208-40E7-9439-94125AF29B4D/HomiesMasterDetailed.app> (loaded)' with name 'StoresViewController''

Comment: whats a name of your XIB file ?

Comment: then whats the identifier you used for this view ?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "eNX-d3-04R-view-zfQ-CW-RSv" nib but didn't get a UITableView.' Meybe I should change something in storyboard?

Comment: also you need to check "StoresViewController" files, may be there is some error.. according to me in "StoresViewController" class you point out delegate and datasource but did not put require delegate methods like numberofrowsintableview, cellforrowatindexpath, etc..not sure but may be thats why this was happen

Comment: Put Breakpoint on your Loadview and see why your application was crashed, this was an issue in your navigated page, your this issue is solved

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com/file/igv31p I want to do something like in Kayak app. What is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
StoresViewController *storeView = [[StoresViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StoresViewController" bundle:nil];
```

simply passed the nib when you create the objcet.